# OpenGL scanline algorithm - does it use rays and bounding boxes?

Tags: opengl, graphics, rasterizing, scanline

I'm studying how scanline algorithms work and I'm wondering whether to determine the closest hit per each pixel a ray is shooted like ray tracing algorithms and, in that case, if bounding boxes are used to determine if there's an intersection or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, [OpenGL is not a ray tracer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667218/ray-tracing-in-modern-opengl-where-do-i-begin?rq=1). For depth testing you would typically use a depth buffer (check Wikipedia).