# What are the things need to learn to write a Shader code?

Tags: graphics, shader

For someone with no background about Graphics Design, how should anyone start learning GLSL? I started seeing Shadertoy code but don't understand the variables and syntaxes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest looking at a resource like https://learnopengl.com/. This website a ton of comprehensive modern OpenGL tutorials and goes into depth about GLSL shaders in a few of them. ShaderToy shader code works a bit differently than normal graphics applications and is explained nicely in this question's answer:

[WebGL/GLSL - How does a ShaderToy work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449590/webgl-glsl-how-does-a-shadertoy-work)